# Strange diff behaviour

Tags: linux, ssh, diff, expect

I have a file called `this.txt` that has this content:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Which I generate using: `ls /home > this.txt`

Then I create a file called `that.txt` that has this content:

```
a
c
d
f
```

Which I generate using: `ssh -p 1111 root@176.178.1.8 'ls /home' > that.txt`

When I compare both using `diff this.txt that.txt` I get normal results.

Then I get the file `that2.txt` using an `expect` script to avoid typing the password for the ssh connection, with this content

```
a
c
d
f
```

Using `cat` I compare (visually) both files and are the same, but when I use `diff this.txt that.txt` I get results with no sense (it says that nothing from `this.txt` is in `that2.txt`).

Also if I use `diff that.txt that2.txt` I get the no sense result.

Maybe is because I'm using two different interpreters (because I use expect and bash) and the files are coded different? Any ideas?

PD: hopefully I explained myself. I'm not an English speaker and this is my first question.

Comment: Can you do `cat -vte that2.txt` and show its output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I somewhat “normalized” your markup, it might be a good idea if you looked over my changes for future reference – just because uniformity makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherCreutzig for the formatting. I'll do it that way the next time. I love thius community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d assume you have files with either blanks at the ends of lines or different end-of-line markers, possibly both. Please compare the outputs of `od -c that.txt` and `od -c that2.txt`. Also, it may be worth checking the file sizes.

Oh, and I should add that you do not need to put your password into an `expect` script. ssh can work with public key pairs, a **much** safer alternative, and not really hard to set up. Check `man ssh-keygen` for a start.

Comment: CRLF line terminators, maybe?

Comment: Thanks! That `od` command did the trick. With that I realized that each line in that.txt ended with \n while each line in that2.txt ended with \r\n.

So I used `tr -d '\r' > that2.txt` and now `diff this.txt that.txt` and `diff this.txt that2.txt` shows the same results.